# MSAL iOS - Broker Authentication

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

**Is it possible to disable broker authentication in MSAL iOS app? How?
I could not disable this in my app**

Answer (score 1):

You can set `MSALGlobalConfig.brokerAvailability = .none`.

Comment: Perfect! Wasn't able to find it in docs, but SO and @blyscuit helped! Tested on device, works as expected. You still want to configure all the auth schemes needed by the broker, otherwise the client won't be created.